# How to add an element if a div is clicked but remove the same element from the others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, createelement

I have an onclick function that add an  element if a div is clicked

```
function clickOnADivToCreateLi(element) {
  var div = $(element);
  var i = document.createElement("i");
  $(i).addClass("fas fa-check-circle clicked");
  div.append(i);
}
```

But when I click on another div with the same class, I have two div with the same `<i>` and if I click again that div will have 2 `<i>`s

How do add the `<i>` but at the same time remove it from the others?

Comment: `$('i.fas.clicked').remove()` before you do anything.  https://api.jquery.com/remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the `i` elements matching the classes you assigned to it and call `remove()` before creating the new instance.

Also note that your code can be made much more succinct:

```
function clickOnADivToCreateLi(element) {
  $('i.fas.fa-check-circle.clicked').remove();
  $(element).append('<i class="fas fa-check-circle clicked" />');
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your fast respose, it worked